# Why isn't my variable accepting all values in my program

Tags: python

I'm making a program that calculates salary by taking in input from a .txt file. It opens it, then runs it through an if/else statement to see where it falls under and calculates a certain percentage increase based off the amount of money it is. I had 3 lists for all three parts, oldSalary, newSalary, and salaryList, but I had to remove salaryList because those were the instructions. I zipped oldSalary and newSalary so I could print them together, and I got the salaries to print next to it as well, but the issue is that it prints only the last value in that list, which in this case is '4', so it only says 4% when you do it, instead of 7%, 5.5%, etc. If you want to run it, the code is at https://pastebin.pl/view/06d10283 and the input is on https://pastebin.pl/view/40195d2c

The part of the code that I am using to print and format it is

```
for x,y in zip(oldSalaryList, newSalaryList):
print(x + '\t '+ y + '\t' + format((pay_raised),'.2f') + '%')
```

I'm not so sure that's the issue, but there it is. If anyone could help me with this, that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`pay_raised` is set to the last value in the while loop.

## With `raises`

If you wanted to change it according to the particular salary, your zip statement should look like this.

```
for x, y, raise in zip(oldSalaryList, newSalaryList, raises):  
    print(x + '\t  ' + y + '\t' + raise)
```

NB: Your `raises` list is already formatted as a string with "%" etc.

## Without `raises` :(

Having the `raise` list is a convenient solution to the problem. If you can't use that, you have to make your own.

```py
for old_salary, new_salary in zip(oldSalaryList, newSalaryList):
    raise = new_salary - old_salary
    raise_in_percent = 100 * diff / old_salary
    print(x + '\t  ' + y + '\t' + format((raise_in_percent),'.2f') + '%')
```

Comment: The issue with that is I'm not allowed to use that as a list, so I have to print it for every new value of the pay_raised variable

Comment: What does "not allowed to use that as a list" mean? At line 37, raises is defined as an empty list.

Comment: That was a mistake in my program, sorry. I tested it as a list previously using zip, since this was for an assignment, but then learned I wasn't allowed to use it as one and forgot to remove the empty list from my code.